# Unable to Enlarge Window Size

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

My app has a Mini Mode, which is entered using these two lines of code:

```
    (Window.Current.Content as Frame).Navigate(typeof(MiniModePage));
    await ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterViewModeAsync(ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay, MiniModePage.ViewModePreferences);
```

This is the `MiniModePage.ViewModePreferences`:

```
    public static Size PageSize { get => new Size(300, Settings.settings.MiniModeWithDropdown ? 900 : 300); }

    public static ViewModePreferences ViewModePreferences
    {
        get
        {
            var pref = ViewModePreferences.CreateDefault(ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay);
            pref.CustomSize = PageSize;
            return pref;
        }
    }
```

In the `MiniModePage`, I allow my app window to be resized by button clicking:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SpinArrowAnimation.Begin();
        Settings.settings.MiniModeWithDropdown = !Settings.settings.MiniModeWithDropdown;
        var size = PageSize;
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(size);
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(size);
    }
```

The problem is that, I am able to shrink the window size down but when I try to enlarge the window from the size of 300 * 300 to 300 * 900, the window size does not change. It always stays 300 * 300.

How can I enable the window to be resized constantly?

Another question I have is that, the 300 * 900 window obviously doesn't have the size ratio of 1 * 3, as is shown in the picture below. How should I fix it?

[image]

[image]

More source code:

1. [MiniModePage](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/MiniModePage.xaml.cs)
2. Code for entering `MiniModePage` is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/MediaControl.xaml.cs) in the `MiniModeButton_Click`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that, I am able to shrink the window size down but when I try to enlarge the window from the size of 300 * 300 to 300 * 900, the window size does not change. It always stays 300 * 300.

Please check [`SetPreferredMinSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.setpreferredminsize#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ApplicationView_SetPreferredMinSize_Windows_Foundation_Size_) documentation,

> The smallest allowed minimum size is 192 x 48 effective pixels. The largest allowed minimum size is 500 x 500 effective pixels. If you set a value outside of these bounds, it is coerced to be within the allowed bounds. (To learn about effective pixels, see Responsive design 101 for .)

So, please edit your largest height 900 to 500.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SpinArrowAnimation.Begin();
    Settings.settings.MiniModeWithDropdown = !Settings.settings.MiniModeWithDropdown;
    var size = new Size(300,500);
    ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(size);
    ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(size);
}
```

Comment: So how should I switch my app between 300 * 300 and 300 * 900?

Comment: Please check the official document [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/winrt-api/issues/725)  Compact Overlay dev here. The min and max sizes are not outlined anywhere on MSDN, so I keep getting mail asking for how the sizing works. Min size is 150epx x 150epx.
Max size is min(500epx, half the width in pixels of the screen the window is on) x min(500epx, half the height in pixels of the screen the window is on) Where epx is Effective Pixels or scaled pixels.